# How can I use Cypress to crawl a website for links?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, browser-automation

I understand that Cypress is designed for e2e testing and is not a generic browser automation tool. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to use Cypress to log into a website and crawl through it pulling all the hrefs, thus building a list of the pages you'd like to test.

For a large website, this seems almost necessary for certain kinds of e2e tests, but I'm stuck trying to implement it. Here's what I have:

```
describe('Link crawler', () => {
  const linksQueue = ['www.example.com/'];
  const seen = {};

    before(() => {
      cy.login(email, password);
    });

    // Build a queue, typical BFS algorithm.
    // For all links in the queue, pull out the anchor tags and add new hrefs to the queue.
    // Mark links as seen so you don't infinitely loop.
    while (linksQueue.length) {
      let currentLink = linksQueue.pop();
      it(`${currentLink} should have links.`, () => {

        cy.visit(`${currentLink}`);

        cy.window().then(win => {
          let anchorTags = win.document.getElementsByTagName('a');
          for (let idx = 0; idx < anchorTags.length; ++idx) {
            let newLink = anchorTags[idx].href;

            if (!(newLink in seen)) {
              linksQueue.unshift(newLink);
            }
            seen[newLink] = true;
          }
        });
      });
    }
});
```

The problem with the above is that Cypress only processes what's in the queue to begin with, so this will run and extract links, but only on 'www.example.com/'.

How can I use Cypress to work over a queue of links that continues to grow? Is there something else I can use besides cy.window?

I've made this work using Puppeteer, but it would be great to use a single library and Cypress is my team's tool of choice for e2e.

Comment: It looks like you are recursively checking all links which could result in you crawling the entire internet! I would suggest checking page by page, similar to this blog post: https://filiphric.com/testing-links-with-cypress.